# (Ruby on Rails) How to import some data from xml into a relation table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, nokogiri

I have 3 tables. One of them is a relation table stored the relationship of the other two. `Courses`, `Staff`, and **`Courses-staff`** (this is the relation table). There was no primary key in my Courses table, so I want to let Rails help me set it (`id`). But when I import these data from an xml into my sqlite tables, I don't know the `id` of each entry in my Courses table. How can I store the primary keys of these two tables into my "`Courses-staff`" table ??

Comment: If there was no primary key in your Courses table, what type of reference do you store in the Courses-Staff table?

Comment: What does your schema look like? What does the XML look like? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really explain *what you've tried*, so it's hard for anyone to answer the question. If your XML is formulated as such:

```
<course>
  <something>bla</something>
  <somethingElse>blabla</somethingElse>
  <staffIDs>
    <staffID>124233</staffID>
    <staffID>123532</staffID>
  </staff>
</course>
<staff>
  <staffMember>
    <staffID>124233</staffID>
    <staffName>Jim</staffName>
  </staffMember>
  <staffMember>
    <staffID>123532</staffID>
    <staffName>Sophia</staffName>
  </staffMember>
</staff>
```

Then make sure that you parse and create the Staff first, then when you're parsing the Courses, you can do something like (pseudocode):

```
courses.each do |c|
  # ...
  staffIDs.each do |s|
    @course.staff << Staff.find_by_external_id(s)
  end
end
```